# Receiving null byte array from simulator

Tags: c#

This is my code for a client to receive data from a server which is the simulator. While debugging the code, I received null values in this array, called `receivedBytes`:

```
// define buffer
byte[] receivedBytes = new byte[2048];

// define endpoint
IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.Resolve("192.168.1.55");
IPAddress ipAddress = ipHost.AddressList[0];
IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 1001);

// connect
Console.WriteLine("Starting: Creating Socket object");
Socket sender = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
sender.Connect(ipEndPoint);
Console.WriteLine("Successfully connected to {0}", sender.RemoteEndPoint);

// get user input
Console.WriteLine("Enter Client Message :");
string sendingMessage = Console.ReadLine();

// send 
Console.WriteLine("Creating message:{0}", sendingMessage);
byte[] forwardMessage = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(sendingMessage);
sender.Send(forwardMessage);

// receive
int totalBytesReceived = sender.Receive(receivedBytes);
Console.WriteLine("Message provided from server: {0}", Encoding.Unicode.GetString(receivedBytes, 0, totalBytesReceived));

// close
sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
sender.Close();
Console.ReadLine();
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "null value" for a `byte`. Why are you using `Encoding.Unicode` here? Is it really returning data in UTF-16?

Comment: By "null bytes", do you mean "bytes with the value 0"? A `byte[]` **cannot physically contain** a `null`. It can, however, contain 0s.

Comment: actually client receiving bytes with the 0 value

Answer (score 0):

Actually the conversion code is wrong.

```
        string sendingMessage = "Hello, World";
        byte[] forwardMessage = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(sendingMessage);
        string receivedMessage = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(forwardMessage, 0,forwardMessage.Length);
```

After that receivedMessage will be broken.

What it does? It gets default encoding to GetBytes and than uses UTF-16 encoding to get string. You should use Encoding.Default.GetBytes and Encoding.Default.GetString.

Comment: after doing this..still totalBytesReceived =0

Comment: Previously you said that "actually client receiving bytes with the 0 value". So in reality you don't receive anything? I suppose the problem is that your socket is not blocking. That's why you exit from Receive immediately and receive nothing.

For a quick fix insert something like "Thread.Sleep(1000)" between "Send" and "Receive" to give server time to receive bytes. For a good fix I need to understand what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: actually m sending one command like '2050fa' command to server which is a simmulator and after sending that command i want to receive message i.e like '2070fa' , but after sending message..client is not receiving anything..that is the main problem